# why collision between two moving objects on pygame dont work?

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection, collision

I am doing a snake game(there is two snakes on the game) with pygame and i want to detect when the snake head collides with the another snake body, do that for both and a special case when the both heads collides, im doing currently the collision between the snake head and the other snake body, it works fine if one of the snakes is frozen and the other is moving, but if both is moving the collision just dont work
heres the code that moves the snakes:

```py
new_pos = None
        if direction == 'DOWN':
            new_pos = (snake[0][0], snake[0][1] + size)
        if direction == 'UP':
            new_pos = (snake[0][0], snake[0][1] - size)
        if direction == 'LEFT':
            new_pos = (snake[0][0] - size, snake[0][1])
        if direction == 'RIGHT':
            new_pos = (snake[0][0] + size, snake[0][1])
        if new_pos:
            snake = [new_pos] + snake
            del snake[-1]
```

keep in mind that the code that movements the other snake is the same but snake turns into snake2, new_pos into new_pos2, etc

collision code:

```py
if snake2[0] in snake[1:]:
            gameOverBlue()

if snake2[0] in snake[1:]:
            gameOverRed()
```

edit: i figured I should put the code that makes the snake too:

```py
#snake
    size = 15
    s_pos = 60
    snake = [(s_pos + size * 2, s_pos),(s_pos + size, s_pos),(s_pos, s_pos)]
    s_skin = pygame.Surface((size, size))
    s_skin.fill((82,128,208))
#snake2
    size2 = 15
    s2_pos = 195
    snake2 = [(s2_pos + size2 * 2, s2_pos),(s2_pos + size2, s2_pos),(s2_pos, s2_pos)]
    s2_skin = pygame.Surface((size2, size2))
    s2_skin.fill((208,128,82))
```

Comment: Second collision check should be snake[0] in snake2[1:]: ?

Comment: Also you are not checking for head-head collisions.

Comment: oh right, let me see if it works changing that edit: doesnt work either, and i know im not checking for head to head collisions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to evaluate whether the head of `snake` is in the list `snake2`, including the head of `snake2`:

```py
if snake[0] in snake2:
    gameOverBlue()
```

and if the head of `snake2` is in `snake`:

```py
if snake2[0] in snake:
    gameOverRed()
```

If you want to detect if the heads of the snakes are colliding the you have to compare `snake[0]` and `snake2[0]` separately:

```py
if snake[0] == snake2[0]:
    print("heads are colliding")

if snake[0] in snake2[1:]:
    gameOverBlue()
if snake2[0] in snake[1:]:
    gameOverRed()
```

Comment: it works, but how can i add a case where the head collides with the head?

Comment: @zac I've extended the answer.