# how to make snake wall teleportation with pygame

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection

I'm making a snake game and I want to teleport my snake, when it goes on a certain wall it teleports to another on the opposite side, but when I tried to do it I got a lot of 'bugs' but my main problem is when the snake goes trough the walls a lot of times it gets off the grid, and all collisions get messed up, here is the snake code:

```py
size = 15
    s_posx = 60
    s_posy = 60
    snake = [(s_posx + size * 2, s_posy),(s_posx + size, s_posy),(s_posx, s_posy)]
    s_skin = pygame.Surface((size, size))
    s_skin.fill((82,128,208))
```

here is the snake movement code:

```py
new_pos = None
        if direction == 'DOWN':
            new_pos = (snake[0][0], snake[0][1] + size)
        if direction == 'UP':
            new_pos = (snake[0][0], snake[0][1] - size)
        if direction == 'LEFT':
            new_pos = (snake[0][0] - size, snake[0][1])
        if direction == 'RIGHT':
            new_pos = (snake[0][0] + size, snake[0][1])
        if new_pos:
            snake = [new_pos] + snake
            del snake[-1]
```

and here is the wall teleportation code:

```py
if snake[0][0] == 0:
            _pos = (1020, (snake[0][1]/15) * 15)
            if _pos:
                snake = [_pos] + snake
                del snake[-1]
        elif snake[0][1] == 0:
            _pos = ((snake[0][0]/ 15) * 15,580)
            if _pos:
                snake = [_pos] + snake
                del snake[-1]
        elif snake[0][0] == 1020:
            _pos = (0, (snake[0][1]/ 15) * 15)
            if _pos:
                snake = [_pos] + snake
                del snake[-1]
        elif snake[0][1] == 580:
            _pos = ((snake[0][0] / 15) * 15, 0)
            if _pos:
                snake = [_pos] + snake
                del snake[-1]
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get the point about the part of the snake that is out the window.

Comment: I dont blame you, my skills on english communication isnt yet so good

Comment: You're English is fine. Even better than mine. Communication in foreign languages ​​leads to misunderstandings. That's life. Anyway, I see my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

580 is not divisible by 15. That is probably the mistake. Change it to 585. According to your previous question ([why collision between two moving objects on pygame dont work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64539458/why-collision-between-two-moving-objects-on-pygame-dont-work)), the collision test will only work if the snake's coordinates are divisible by 15. Your code looks fine. However I recommend to simplify it:

```py
_pos = None
if snake[0][0] == 0:
    _pos = (1020, snake[0][1])
elif snake[0][1] == 0:
    _pos = (snake[0][0], 585)
elif snake[0][0] == 1020:
    _pos = (0, snake[0][1]/ 15)
elif snake[0][1] == 585:
    _pos = (snake[0][0], 0)
if _pos:
    snake = [_pos] + snake
    del snake[-1]
```